# Pdf Text Coordinate / Font

Tags: java, pdf, text, fonts, coordinate

I have a project, i have to get title,author informations from inside of the PDF file(not from metaData). So i try to read text from PDF by given coordinates and try to get fonts of texts.

Is there any way to do that, can anyone give advise ? Or is there another solutions to do my project?

Thanks for every help and thought you're sharing with me.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple PDF libraries for Java which allow you to extract text, my favourite being [iText](http://itextpdf.com/), as examples for text parsing have a look at [ExtractPageContentArea](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=279) and other [examples](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=15) from chapter 15 of iText in Action, 2nd edition.

Currently there is no example making use of the font information, but the information is available to the RenderListeners.